# Block web browser FTP integration on CentOs 6

Tags: linux, browser, centos, ftp

I'm switching over to a new provider and I can't remember what I did on my old server to block browser FTP log in.

What I mean by browser log in, is that someone can go to a web browser and type "`ftp://domain.com`" and brute it if they'd like.

I am running CentOs 6 (64 Bit) with FTP server [VSFTPD](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) (User: Root)